# How can I get a localized message in a grails GSP tag attribute?

Tags: grails, service, internationalization, gsp

In a grails GSP, I want a toolTip to be localized:

```
<a href="..." title="localizedMessage">
```

As the toolTip is written in the attribute title, I can't use `<g:message>` here. Actually I already have a service for localized messages, but when I call it from the GSP, the service's messageSource is null, so getting that to work would be a solution as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can invoke the tag directly:

```
<a href="..." title="${message(code:'your.localized.message.code')}">
```

I think this should work too:

```
<a href="..." title="${g.message(code:'your.localized.message.code')}">
```